# How to fix Application force closes issue when device is turned on?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, gallery

I have developed simple android imageview that uses viewpager, and it plays music in background. It also stops music when last image is reached and it will resume the music when user slides back to the images. However, my main problem is that when device goes to sleep music stops and when device starts again instead of resuming music again and displaying image..It force closes... Any suggestion on how to fix this issue...Following are my codes...

Mainactivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.view.Menu;

import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        MediaPlayer oursong;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        oursong = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.a);
        oursong.seekTo(0);
         oursong.start();
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        final ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
         viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
         viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int pos) {
            if (pos == adapter.getCount() - 1)

             {
              oursong.pause();

               } else if (!oursong.isPlaying()) 

                                        { 
                oursong.start();

               }         
               }

               @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                 }

                 @Override
                 public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                  }
                 });
        }

        private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // Inflate menu resource file.
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

                // Locate MenuItem with ShareActionProvider
                MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);

                // Fetch and store ShareActionProvider
                mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();
                // Return true to display menu
                return true;
        }

        // Call to update the share intent
        private void setShareIntent(Intent shareIntent) {
                if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
                        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
                }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
                super.onPause();
                oursong.release();
        }
}
```

ImageAdapter.java

```
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    Context context;
    private final int[] GalImages = new int[] {
        R.drawable.one,
        R.drawable.two,
        R.drawable.three
    };    
    ImageAdapter(Context context){
        this.context=context;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
      return GalImages.length;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
      return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
      ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
      int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding_small);
      imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
      imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
      imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);  
      imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

           public void onClick(View view) {

                    WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager  = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);
                    try {
                            myWallpaperManager.setResource(GalImages[position]);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                             e.printStackTrace();
                    }      
           }
           });
      ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
      return imageView;
    }
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
      ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
    }
  }
```

Logcat errors.... (Following Logcat was taken when app was running on actual device)

```
08-29 02:48:21.051: I/dalvikvm(2880): Could not find method android.widget.ShareActionProvider.setShareIntent, referenced from method com.manishkpr.viewpagerimagegallery.MainActivity.setShareIntent
08-29 02:48:21.051: W/dalvikvm(2880): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3259: Landroid/widget/ShareActionProvider;.setShareIntent (Landroid/content/Intent;)V
08-29 02:48:21.051: D/dalvikvm(2880): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
08-29 02:48:21.066: I/dalvikvm(2880): Could not find method android.view.MenuItem.getActionProvider, referenced from method com.manishkpr.viewpagerimagegallery.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu
08-29 02:48:21.066: W/dalvikvm(2880): VFY: unable to resolve interface method 2912: Landroid/view/MenuItem;.getActionProvider ()Landroid/view/ActionProvider;
08-29 02:48:21.066: D/dalvikvm(2880): VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0010
08-29 02:48:21.066: D/dalvikvm(2880): VFY: dead code 0x0013-0019 in Lcom/manishkpr/viewpagerimagegallery/MainActivity;.onCreateOptionsMenu (Landroid/view/Menu;)Z
08-29 02:48:21.230: W/MediaPlayer-cpp(2880): info/warning (802, 0)
08-29 02:48:21.348: I/MediaPlayer(2880): Info (802,0)
08-29 02:48:21.434: D/dalvikvm(2880): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1117 objects / 212256 bytes in 71ms
08-29 02:48:36.644: D/dalvikvm(2880): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 553 objects / 29584 bytes in 32ms
08-29 02:50:00.566: D/AndroidRuntime(2880): Shutting down VM
08-29 02:50:00.566: W/dalvikvm(2880): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d8a8)
08-29 02:50:00.605: E/AndroidRuntime(2880): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-29 02:50:00.605: E/AndroidRuntime(2880): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.manishkpr.viewpagerimagegallery/com.manishkpr.viewpagerimagegallery.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException
08-29 02:50:00.605: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3128)
08-29 02:50:00.605: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3143)
08-29 02:50:00.605: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2059)
08-29 02:50:00.605: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-29 02:50:00.605: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-29 02:50:00.605: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-29 02:50:00.605: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-29 02:50:00.605: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-29 02:50:00.605: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-29 02:50:00.605: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-29 02:50:00.605: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-29 02:50:00.605: E/AndroidRuntime(2880): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
08-29 02:50:00.605: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.seekTo(Native Method)
08-29 02:50:00.605: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at com.manishkpr.viewpagerimagegallery.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:86)
08-29 02:50:00.605: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1149)
08-29 02:50:00.605: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3823)
08-29 02:50:00.605: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3118)
08-29 02:50:00.605: E/AndroidRuntime(2880):     ... 10 more
08-29 02:50:10.371: I/Process(2880): Sending signal. PID: 2880 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Can you post the logcat ?

Comment: @113408...Sorry..I cannot post logcat ..there is something wrong with my emulator...

Comment: @ 113408...finally got my emulator working today...please see above logcat error...

Comment: This log cat is not associated to the problem you are saying your encountering this is talking about a Latin Dictionary failing to open, do you have some third party library dependency?

Comment: @ inner_class7...no...lemme restart my emulator again..

Comment: why don't you try to run this on a different version of Android API too, this is a bizarre error, could have something to do with your ShareActionProvider vs. version of Android you are building on.

Comment: @inner_class7....How about now ?

Comment: @inner_class7...ok lemme try API 17...I also believe its because of shareAction provider..

Comment: @ inner_class7 ..pasted new logcat..

Comment: your emulator is not configured right, moreover none of these logs are associated to your code.. try filtering your logcat to use app:{package name goes here}

Comment: @ inner_class7...sorry to bother you but I can see my app running in my emulator..

Comment: Is this still an issue?

Comment: @ inner_class7...yes...is there any code that can display logcat errors ?

Comment: @inner_class7...I tried every thing from restarting of eclipse to computer. I  even tried forcing adb through taskmanager...but unfortunatly nothing worked..

Comment: @inner_class7...please see my edited Log cat..I am not sure if this is what you are looking for...If not..please let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving your music playback to onResume() Activity lifecycle with fragments won't call onCreate() again until you activity is 're created. So the playback won't be resumed without closing your app.

Something like this

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.view.Menu;

import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer oursong;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    ImageAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         oursong = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.a);
         oursong.seekTo(0);
         oursong.start();

         viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
         adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
         viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);


         viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(MyViewPagerListener);
    }

    private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate menu resource file.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

            // Locate MenuItem with ShareActionProvider
            MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);

            // Fetch and store ShareActionProvider
            mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();
            // Return true to display menu
            return true;
    }

    // Call to update the share intent
    private void setShareIntent(Intent shareIntent) {
            if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
                    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
            }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();

           if(oursong != null){
               oursong.release();
            }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
          super.onResume();

         /*
          * This is the important part, basically since your releasing the song
          * in onPause() you are getting rid of its reference, in this case check
          * if your song is null then if it is re-create it, else you can reuse the
          * the original, but i suspect that calling release() in onPause() allows the
          * song to get cleaned up by Java's Garbage Collector.
          */
         if(oursong == null){
            oursong = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.a);
            oursong.seekTo(0); // You will probably want to save an int to restore here
            oursong.start();
         }else{
            oursong.seekTo();
            oursong.start();
         }

    }

   /*
    * May want to add two methods here: onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outstate) &
    * onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) to maintain playback position
    * in onResume instead of just restarting the song.
    */

   private final OnPageChangeListener MyViewPagerListener = new OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int pos) {
              if (pos == adapter.getCount() - 1){
                 // adding null checks for safety
                 if(oursong != null){
                    oursong.pause();
                 }

               } else if (!oursong.isPlaying()){ 

                // adding null check for safety
                if(oursong != null){
                    oursong.start();
                }
              }         
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        };

 }
```

Hope this helps you resolve your problem.

Comment: @inner_class7....I am sorry... But I am new to android..It would be helpful.. if you explain in detail..like moving this code here and there..thanks for reply..

Comment: Sorry for the short explanation I will post some code for you in the morning. But the short of it would be to override onResume using the override/ implement choice from right clicking in your activity file. Then select onResume() from the wizard. And move your media playback instantiation into the onResume so you don't get null pointer and playback resumes when the activity resumes

Comment: @ inner_class7....thanks again..and it would be great if you post it in pastebin..or here too..

Comment: @ inner_class7..I am getting yellow bulb with red cross.. near this code  oursong.seekTo(); and it says "The method SeekTo (Int) in the type media player is not applicable for the arguments "

Comment: @inner_class7...I tried to replaced like this  oursong.seekTo(0);   ......But it didn't solve my problem :(

Comment: what? I am using this as the code you posted... just moved some code around and restructured to call in onResume...

Comment: i am confused by your issue now, can you post the problem you are facing? The MediaPlayer class in android has a seekTo(int milliseconds) method there should be no issue with passing an int value to it.

Comment: @ inner_class7...My issue is that when my app running on any device goes to sleep ..It stop music and displaying image.Which is what I want .... HOWEVER, when the device is tuned on again ..Instead of resuming the music and images...it display pop up dialogue box saying..."Sorry the application has stopped unexpectedly..please try again"

Comment: Please add the logcat you are receiving for this. It could be a number of issues.